# How to add text inside an SVG path

Tags: svg

I have an svg image, I want to add text inside the path element however it doesn't seem to inside the image, just around it.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g id="Templates">
        <path id="cloud"
              d="M17,10.57a3,3,0,0,1,1.18.23,3.11,3.11,0,0,1,1,.64,2.82,2.82,0,0,1,.65,1,3,3,0,0,1-1.6,3.95,3.08,3.08,0,0,1-1.16.23H8a4,4,0,0,1-1.56-.31,4,4,0,0,1,0-7.38A4,4,0,0,1,8,8.57a3.54,3.54,0,0,1,.73.07,4.63,4.63,0,0,1,.72-.87,4.72,4.72,0,0,1,.89-.65,4.58,4.58,0,0,1,1-.41,4.79,4.79,0,0,1,1.13-.14,4.37,4.37,0,0,1,1.64.3,4.55,4.55,0,0,1,1.36.84,4.39,4.39,0,0,1,1,1.27A4.66,4.66,0,0,1,17,10.57Z"
              style="fill:#1d2639" />
    </g>
    <text font-size="2">
        <textPath href="#cloud" text-anchor="middle">
            CLOUDD
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

How to place the text in the center of the cloud.

Comment: in this case (it may not work with other shapes) you can get the bounding box of the cloud with getBBox and calculate it's center. Next you place the text in this point with text-anchor="middle" and dominant-baseline="middle"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `side="left|right"` attribute can be used for placing the text on a specific side. This can be used in combination with `dominant-baseline="auto|hanging"` to make the text stick to the bottom or top of the text.

In this example I also added the `pathLength` attribute to the `<path>` to control the position along the path together with `startOffset` on the `<textPath>`. And a stroke to the `<path>` so that the text is not directly on the edge of the cloud.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <g id="Templates">
    <path id="cloud" d="M17,10.57a3,3,0,0,1,1.18.23,3.11,3.11,0,0,1,1,.64,2.82,2.82,0,0,1,.65,1,3,3,0,0,1-1.6,3.95,3.08,3.08,0,0,1-1.16.23H8a4,4,0,0,1-1.56-.31,4,4,0,0,1,0-7.38A4,4,0,0,1,8,8.57a3.54,3.54,0,0,1,.73.07,4.63,4.63,0,0,1,.72-.87,4.72,4.72,0,0,1,.89-.65,4.58,4.58,0,0,1,1-.41,4.79,4.79,0,0,1,1.13-.14,4.37,4.37,0,0,1,1.64.3,4.55,4.55,0,0,1,1.36.84,4.39,4.39,0,0,1,1,1.27A4.66,4.66,0,0,1,17,10.57Z"
      style="fill:#1d2639" stroke="#1d2639"
      stroke-width="1" pathLength="100"/>
  </g>
  <text font-size="2">
    <textPath href="#cloud" fill="white" text-anchor="start"
      dominant-baseline="auto" side="right" startOffset="55">
        CLOUDD
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

### Update

Here is a version where the text is just placed in the middle of the SVG.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <g id="Templates">
    <path id="cloud" d="M17,10.57a3,3,0,0,1,1.18.23,3.11,3.11,0,0,1,1,.64,2.82,2.82,0,0,1,.65,1,3,3,0,0,1-1.6,3.95,3.08,3.08,0,0,1-1.16.23H8a4,4,0,0,1-1.56-.31,4,4,0,0,1,0-7.38A4,4,0,0,1,8,8.57a3.54,3.54,0,0,1,.73.07,4.63,4.63,0,0,1,.72-.87,4.72,4.72,0,0,1,.89-.65,4.58,4.58,0,0,1,1-.41,4.79,4.79,0,0,1,1.13-.14,4.37,4.37,0,0,1,1.64.3,4.55,4.55,0,0,1,1.36.84,4.39,4.39,0,0,1,1,1.27A4.66,4.66,0,0,1,17,10.57Z"
      style="fill:#1d2639" />
  </g>
  <text font-size="2" x="12" y="12" text-anchor="middle"
  dominant-baseline="middle" fill="white">CLOUDD</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is it possible to display the text in a straight line in the center of the cloud? It seems to stick to the edges (inside the cloud) even when I play around with the values you provided

Comment: @rishi the hole idea with `<textPath>` is that the text follows a path. If you just want the text centered in the middle it makes life mush easier – I will update my answer.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood the concept of textPath. Thank you so much.